# Add computed column with "IN" syntax

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, computed-column

I have a query in SQL Server 2008R2 that I want to run against a computed column that in turn I am going to index - in order to speed things up.

The column is of type int right now.

I cannot get the syntax right.

```
alter table dbo.tOutput Add StateNew as State IN (0, 10)
```

I get an error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
```

The query, coming from C# entity framework, should then later on use the index and - well - be fast.

The C# seems to be converted to the IN usage, the original is like this:

```
tOutput.Where(x => (x.State == 0) || (x.State == 10))
```

The generated SQL reads

```
.. FROM tOutput WHERE State IN (0, 10) ..
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that you want a computed column here. It looks like what you really need is a filtered index (introduced in SQL Server 2008), using `WHERE [State] IN (0, 10)` as the filter. Once this index is created, queries that have that same predicate should use this index. Please take a look at:

- [Create Filtered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes)
- [CREATE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql#filtered-indexes)

Just FYI: a computed column is an expression that needs to return a scalar value. `State IN (0, 10)` is not a scalar expression, which is why you are getting the error. You could modify it to be something like `CONVERT(TINYINT, CASE [State] WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, but then indexing that will still include all rows. Using a filtered index will only include the matching rows, which will be smaller and faster :-).

Comment: Isnt a bit/bool a scalar value? I think the filtered index should work though, too. Did not think about it, since it does not work on a computed column, but in my case, the column is not computed.

Comment: @AndreasReiff SQL Server does not have boolean type so ther can be no scalar boolean values. If the expression was modified to yield an INT or a BIT, it would be accepted, i.e.: `.. ADD StateNew AS CASE WHEN State IN (0, 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @AndreasReiff A `bit` value is a scalar value, BUT `State IN (0, 10)` does not return a _value_; it evaluates to a boolean true / false, which is similar, but not the same. For example, you can do `IF (State IN (0, 10))...` but you cannot do `SELECT ([State] IN (0, 10)) AS [YesOrNo] FROM ...`. This is why I have the note in the "Just FYI" section showing how to represent this as a scalar expression for use in a computed column. But again, the filtered index is better than a non-filtered index on a computed column.

Comment: You can do that in PostgreSQL. ;) `SELECT x IN (1,2) FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(4) ) AS t(x);` Having a boolean type is awesome!

Comment: @EvanCarroll interesting...thanks for mentioning :-)